# Send data from the controller to phtml

Tags: magento-1, controllers, phtml, design

I have this controller:

```
...
public function insertAction() {
    $something = 'testcase';
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_title($this->__("the title"));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
...
```

I would like to access `$something` in my .phtml document, how do I do this? (or to put it in another way: how can I access `$something` in my .phtml file)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

**Assign directly to the Block:**

```
$block->assign($var);
```

or

```
$block->assign(array('myvar'=>'value','anothervar'=>true));
```

Then you can access it in the phtml file like this:

```
$this->myvar
```

**Use the Mage registry:**

```
Mage::register('custom_var', $var);
```

and then use it like:

```
$var = Mage::registry('custom_var');
```

Comment: you have used `$block->assign($var)` but how would be retrieved in `phtml` file?

Comment: You would access via `$this->myvar` from within the template file

Comment: I believe it's `Mage::register($key, $value, ...)`. So, `Mage::register('custom_var', $var)`?

Comment: It should be `$block->assign('myvar',$var);`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @philwinkle Does `Mage::register('custom_var', $var); ` write the value in session and this can be accessible from other template file except current action template as well?

Answer (score 19):

Your phtml must be rendered by a block. The block must have a name in the layout.
You can do this after calling `$this->loadLayout();`

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('block_name_here')
if ($block){//check if block actually exists
   $block->setSomething($something);
}
```

Then you can get the value in the `phtml` file like

```
$value = $this->getSomething();
//or 
$value = $this->getData('something');
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me :(, I have a controller which returns the product id through AJAX, for quickview of products.

Comment: @Shathish. This is a different issue. You can rend the response as JSON and use the values in the AJAX response handler.

Comment: Yes I am using JSON to return the block (something.phtml) content and update the div with these details in list page, how can I pass the variable from my controller to something.phtml?

actually I do this currently using $block->assign() method, which I feel isn't the right way (as it is tight coupling - correct me if i'm wrong) or shall I post this as a question?

Comment: @shathish maybe you would ask an other question and hope it doesn't get marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

In case you people missed there is one more way to get this done

using sessions

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setSomeSessionVar($data);// In the Controller
$data = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSomeSessionVar(); // In the View;
```

[source](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/196817/)

Comment: Even if you has the data in the session to use it later, I recommend to use `$block->setSomething()` or `$block->assign()`. This feels like "too much code" and it should be as much php as possible avoided.

Answer (score -1):

If you're within your block controller.

```
class module_namespace_Block_example extends Mage_Core_Block_Template 
{
      protected $_var;

     public function __construct(){

         $this->_var = "something"; 


     }
}
```

Then in your .phtml file

```
   <?php 
        $variable = $this->_var;
        echo $variable; // prints "something"

   ?>

   <h1>You're inside your phtml file...... <?php echo $variable;  //prints "something" ?></h1>
```

Comment: What you call "block controller" is just called a "block" in Magento. The question was about controller actions found in the `controllers` directory of a module.

Answer (score -4):

this is very easy to send data from controller to phtml file.

Step1:- Firstly create the Model class and extends from Varien_Object

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Modelfilename extends Varien_Object
{

}
```

step2:- Now Open the contollerfile and put the code in the function.

```
$name='gaurav';
$this->loadLayout();
Mage::getSingleton('Modulename/Modelfilename')->setData('name',$name);
$this->renderLayout();
```

Step3:- Open the phtml file and put the code.

```
echo $name=Mage::getSingleton('Modulename/Modelfilename')->getData('name');
```

Output:- 'gaurav';