# how i can get the assign value in phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

how to i can get the assign value in phtml file.
i am using this code this to assign value but i don't know how to retrieve it in phtml file.

```
$this->loadLayout()->getLayout()->getBlock('blockname')
     ->assign('active', 'company');
```

i am getting by this but no value is showing.

```
<?php echo $this->Active;?>
```

any help will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of assign you can use set and get method of Varient it is great features of OOP used by magento

use like this

```
$this->loadLayout()->getLayout()->getBlock('blockname')
     ->setActive('company');
```

and you can get this in phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getActive();?> // will print company.
```

its the best you to assign value and get in to phtml files or any call.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: thanks it worked. can you tell what was the problem in my code?

Comment: see this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/send-data-from-the-controller-to-phtml. its using nesting array as argument